# file handling python selenium automation error

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to get to the following:

```
<button id="plupload" class="newupl" style="position: relative; z-index: 1; opacity: 1;">Add Images</button>in the attached source code
```

[image]

I am using the following code with selenium web driver but the file is not being uploaded as I would like it to be:

```
imageFolder = '/Users/jmath/Desktop/DevelopmentStuff/PythonFiles/climages/'

for files in os.walk(imageFolder):
    for imgfile in files[2]:
        if imgfile.endswith(".jpeg"):
            print(imgfile)
            driver.find_element_by_xpath('/button[@class="newupl"').send_keys(imageFolder + imgfile)
```

Comment: Jonathan, normally, there is a hidden element somewhere that is actually an "input" element that accepts the file names. This is normally where you have to perform the send keys to.  Can you look a little further in the element tree around that element and see if you can find the hidden input. It normally has a @type property of "file".

Answer (score 0):

`<button>` element is not what you actually need to handle file upload. As @AFundeburg has pointed out element that you need to handle is `<input type="file">`. Try below code line and let me know in case of any issues:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//input[@type="file"]').send_keys(os.path.join(imageFolder, imgfile))
```